# Symfony 2 - How to determine the namespace and Bundle name for autoload.php & Appkernel.php

Tags: symfony, namespaces, bundle, composer-php

I'm very new to symfony2 and I cannot find this info:
To register a bundle located in my vendor dir, how to determine the namespace and Bundle name for autoload.php & Appkernel.php?

For example, I have downloaded Luiggio's PHPExcel Bundle. I have place it in vendorDir/ExcelBundle/

Where content is:

```
namespace Liuggio\ExcelBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class LiuggioExcelBundle extends Bundle
{
}
```

What lines should I put in Appkernel and namespace.php?
This and this does not work:

```
new Liuggio\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle()
//'Liuggio\\ExcelBundle' => array($vendorDir. '/PHPExcel'),
```

I cannot use composer or github repo at all, too many proxies and restrictions where I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't place bundles in your `vendor` directory manually. Let Composer do this for you. Not only does Composer know where vendor libraries / bundles should be located, it also adds them to your autoload files and performs some other automated tasks.

To tell Composer which libraries are required, you should add them to your `composer.json`:

```
    "require" : {
        (...)
        "liuggio/ExcelBundle": "~2.0"
    },
```

Next, using the command line, run the `composer update` command:

```
$ php composer.phar update
```

(if you don't have a file `composer.phar` in your project directory, but you have Composer installed globally instead, use the following:)

```
$ composer update
```

This will tell Composer to download the required dependencies, update the autoload script, etc, all automatically. When it's finished, you're ready to go.

If you can't use Composer on your server, then run it locally before you upload your files (although I strongly recommend moving to a server that does allow you to use Composer).

The line you're trying to add to `AppKernel.php` is correct, however it only works after running Composer (or you'd indeed have to download the files and update the autoloader manually, but I'd strongly recommend against that).

### Edit

If you really can't use Composer, do the following:

Place the files of ExcelBundle in the following directory:

```
vendor/liuggio/ExcelBundle/Liuggio/ExcelBundle
```

Your line in `AppKernel.php` was already correct.

Add this line to `autoload_namespaces.php`:

```
'Liuggio\\ExcelBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/liuggio/ExcelBundle'),
```

Last but not least, complain to your system administrator that he's making your work impossible with his stupid security measures.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer, Nic.
Waht you described, is what I tryed at first, because I clearly understood that managing dependencies with composer is the best practice.
BUT, and i did it again to be accurate on the error message, here is my problem (EDIT: on the server AND locallly :D):


 [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
 The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded (HTT
 P/1.1 404 Not Found)

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#http-proxy-or-http-proxy)?

Comment: Anyway, I'd suggest trying to fix that problem, instead of not using Composer.

Comment: I've tried yes setting the HTTP_PROXY env var, as i usually do in a shell console.. but it failed as well, because I dont have the exact URL of the proxies, and there are more than just one proxy to go through (high secured area).
What i would need, is the synthax of the line I have to put in autoload_namespaces.php... because i'm just trying randomly for now. If anyone knows:
`physical: ./vendor/ExcelBundle/LiuggioExcelBundle.php
./app/AppKernel.php: new Liuggio\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle()
and ./vendor/composer/autoload_namespace.php: 'Liuggio' => array($vendorDir. '/ExcelBundle'), `

Comment: In that case, place the bundle files in `vendor/liuggio/ExcelBundle`, not just `vendor/ExcelBundle`. And edit `autoload_namespace.php` accordingly (see updated answer).

Comment: Merci for your answer. I tried what you wrote but it kept failing.
(I wrote on a piece of a paper every way possible to write namespace, bruteforcing the thing, eatthiscomposernoproblemforme style), and the ok line to put in namespace is:
`'liuggio' => array($vendorDir),`
`Last but not least, complain to your system administrator that he's making your work impossible with his stupid security measures.` yeh I know, and if you knew everything, you would go total mad.

Comment: Oops, sorry, I made a mistake with the path where the bundle files should go. It should be `vendor/liuggio/ExcelBundle/Liuggio/Excelbundle` instead of simply `vendor/liuggio/ExcelBundle`... See it like this: `vendor/liuggio/ExcelBundle` is a prefix, from there on the file structure should match the namespace structure. Does that work?

Comment: Didn't try and won't sorry. Too many sub directories give me headaches and reminds me java.com.world.app.pkg.bundle.obj.serialize.take.give.send.smoke.look.tostring() kinda of things...

Comment: In that case, you could try using the previous directory structure, but changing the `composer.json` inside the ExcelBundle, changing `psr-0` into `psr-4`... but I'm not sure if that'll work.

Answer (score 0):

```
new Liuggio\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle(),
```

in AppKernel should be working fine.
This is the namespace of the LuiggioExcelBundle class + the class name. Look how your bundles are loaded, its the same.

What's your error?

You say vendorDir/ExcelBundle/ but its vendor/ExcelBundle right?

And what do you mean by namespace.php? :o

https://github.com/liuggio/ExcelBundle ==> there readme is rly easy to understand, it should help you.

For your "proxies and restriction", composer is a powerful tool, I can help you to use it. Download this soft, the free version is enough http://www.frozenway.com/ (if you cant read french, the 1st input in the header is to translate the website, English is Anglais) With this, you wont have any ports restriction.

Comment: The accurate error I have on my app_dev.php homepage:
 `FatalErrorException: Error: Class 'Liuggio\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle' not found in D:\Documents and Settings\T0148533\Mes Documents\EasyPHP-DevServer-13.1VC9\data\localweb\projects\Symfony\app\AppKernel.php line 27`

Yes sorry its vendor/ etc... wrote vendordir because of the var $vendorDir in vendor/composer/autoload_namespace.php
No, i doubt you can do anything about my proxies. Thanks for the offer, but the link you provide (frozenway) is blocked by the proxies as well. Dommage, je suis français :D. Merci de ton aide.

Comment: Your proxy seems to be great :)
Composer is generating the autoload class of your bundle. In vendors/composer/autload_namespaces.php
Like this:
        'FOS\\UserBundle' => array($vendorDir . '/friendsofsymfony/user-bundle'),

So try

'Liuggio\\ExcelBundle' => array($vendorDir. '/ExcelBundle'),

Comment: My company's proxy are awesome to be honest, not a single ad or suspicious request goes through.
What i would need, is the synthax of the line I have to put in autoload_namespaces.php... because i'm just trying randomly for now. If anyone knows:
`physical: ./vendor/ExcelBundle/LiuggioExcelBundle.php
./app/AppKernel.php: new Liuggio\ExcelBundle\LiuggioExcelBundle()
and ./vendor/composer/autoload_namespace.php: 'Liuggio' => array($vendorDir. '/ExcelBundle'), `